# ¿como convertir una frase en variable?

Tags: javascript

Como convertir esto `<h3 id="com">La mayor sabiduría que existe es conocerse a uno mismo. Galileo Galilei</h3>` en una variable sin que se combierta en esto:

```js
var primero = [ 'La', 'mayor', 'sabiduría', 'que', 'existe', 'es', 'conocerse', 'a', 'uno', 'mismo', 'Galileo', 'Galilei' ];
```

Aquí está el código completo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Segundo Algoritmo</title>
</head>
<body>
        <h3 id="om">La mayor sabiduría que existe es conocerse a uno mismo. Galileo Galilei</h3>
        <br>
        <br>
        <h3>Lista Ordenada Alfabéticamente:</h3>
            <p id="alfa"></p>
            <br>
        <h3>Lista Ordenada por Longitud:</h3>
            <p id="long"></p>
            <br>
        <h3>Frase:</h3>
            <p id="ter"></p>
</body>
<script>
    var primero = [ 'La', 'mayor', 'sabiduría', 'que', 'existe', 'es', 'conocerse', 'a', 'uno', 'mismo', 'Galileo', 'Galilei' ];
    var segundo = primero.slice();
    var tercero = document.getElementById("om").innerHTML;
    var terc = tercero.replace(/a/gi, "");

    primero.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.toLowerCase());
    });

    segundo.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.length > b.length) {
        return 1; //
    }
    if (a.length < b.length) { 
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
    });


    document.getElementById("alfa").innerHTML = primero;
    document.getElementById("long").innerHTML = segundo;
    document.getElementById("ter").innerHTML = terc;
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿qué has intentado por tu cuenta? Sería bueno que editaras tu pregunta y subieras el código de lo que has intentado para poder decirte donde tienes fallas y cómo solucionarlas. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya he actualizado mi pregunta, gracias.

Comment: podrías actualizar tu pregunta poniendo un ejemplo de lo que quieres que sea el resultado

Comment: @otosankf lo que quiero del resultado, creo que los especifico arriba. Gracias.

Comment: Si lo que deseas es capturar el valor del texto que hay en el elemento `<H3>` puedes hacerlo usando: `var primero = document.getElementById('om').innerText.split(' ');`. Esto lo que hace es capturar el texto y ponerlo en un `Array`.

Comment: @MauricioContreras si gracias, eso sí que funcionó

Answer (score 2):

Asumo que te refieres a las frases ordenadas. Necesitas convertir los arrays a cadenas:

```js
document.getElementById("alfa").innerHTML = primero.join(' ');
document.getElementById("long").innerHTML = segundo.join(' ');
```